ReactJs-using ref to update input text field to blank after submit not working,input field not getting cleared
I'm trying to clear the input text field after the submit using ref,but it is not working.I don't want re-renders using  taskRef.current/onChange and without it I can't use value atrribute as it becomes read only so opted ref for this issue,but it is not working as expected.
`import {useState,useRef} from 'react'

const SearchBar = ({onAddTask}) => {
let taskRef = useRef();
  const handleTaskBlur= (e) => {
    taskRef.current = e.target.value;
  }
  const hancldeAddTask = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    onAddTask( taskRef.current);
    taskRef.current='';
  }
  return (
    <div className='h-40 m-3'>
<form className="max-w-md mx-auto" >   
    <div className="relative">
        <div className="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3 pointer-events-none">
        {/* search bar icon */}
                     <svg
      className="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
      aria-hidden="true"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    >
      <path
        stroke="currentColor"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth="2"
        d="m19 19-4-4m0-7A7 7 0 1 1 1 8a7 7 0 0 1 14 0Z"
      />
    </svg>
        </div>
     <input
    ref={taskRef}
  onBlur={handleTaskBlur}
  type="text"
  id="task-input"
  className="block w-full p-4 ps-10 text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:ring-2"
  placeholder="Type a task"
  required
/>

        <button onClick={hancldeAddTask} type="submit" className="text-white absolute end-2.5 bottom-2.5 bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
  )
}

export default SearchBar`

